# DD-WRT on WZR-HP-AG300H: Want XFS support; what firmware has kernel 3.8.13-1?

Tags: kernel, dd-wrt, xfs

I installed latest DD-WRT firmware to my wifi router WZR-HP-AG300H. I got the firmware from [here (05-27-2013-r21676)](ftp://dd-wrt.com/others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2013/05-27-2013-r21676/buffalo_wzr-hp-ag300h/).

I'm currently trying to install XFS file system support because my USB hard disk is formatted with it, but unfortunately DD-WRT firmware doesn't seem to support it.

I found that [XFS module can be installed from internet (kmod-fs-xfs_3.8.13-1_ar71xx.ipk)](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/).
I managed to install libc and opkg (the installer tools), but the module needs kernel 3.8.13-1:

```
root@DD-WRT:/# opkg install kmod-fs-xfs
Installing kmod-fs-xfs (3.8.13-1) to root...
Downloading kmod-fs-xfs_3.8.13-1_ar71xx.ipk.
Collected errors:
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for kmod-fs-xfs:
 *  kernel (= 3.8.13-1-c9fbcbc6c04e6f1cd1482e9b879b485b) *  kernel (= 3.8.13-1-c9fbcbc6c04e6f1cd1482e9b879b485b) * 
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package kmod-fs-xfs.

root@DD-WRT:/# uname -a
Linux DD-WRT 3.9.4 #322 Mon May 27 03:17:08 CEST 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

So, I want to know, what firmware has kernel 3.8.13-1? There are so many revisions and I couldn't find any changelog past 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems almost impossible to determine which versions of the Linux kernel are included with all the DD-WRT firmware versions, so I think I'd take a different tactic here and attempt to compile the xfs module myself. There are numerous tutorials that explain in pretty good details how to accomplish this.

Here are just a few:

- [Compiling custom dd-wrt kernel modules](http://blog.dest-unreach.be/2010/12/01/compiling-custom-dd-wrt-kernel-modules)
- [Building DD-WRT From Source - Official Guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Building_From_Source#Building_DD-WRT_From_Source)

You have a bit of an advantage here in the sense that you should only need to re-compile the XFS kernel module and not the entire DD-WRT firmware, so it should be fairly doable. You'll need to focus on specifically on this section of the DD-WRT  Guide, titled: [Compiling (custom) Kernel modules for DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Development#Compiling_.28custom.29_Kernel_modules_for_DD-WRT).

If this is too much for you to deal with you might want to consider switching to [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), assuming it supports your particular hardware.

If you look through this page, titled: [OpenWRT - USB Storage](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/usb.storage), you'll notice that they provide the XFS kernel module already built, as an option.

Comment: From my testing it seems no DD-WRT firmware contain the exact kernel version (3.8.13-1) so I installed OpenWRT instead. Thanks.